# symfony pdo_pgsql doctrine:database:create does not use parameters

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony 3.1.5 and I am trying to run a simple

`php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

as it is described in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html).

My `parameters.yml`

```
parameters:
    database_host: hhvm_db_1
    database_port: 5432
    database_name: dbname
    database_user: dbuser
    database_password: mypassword
```

My `config.yml`

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_pgsql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

I get the following error messages:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
  An exception occured in driver: [32681]: could not translate host name "hhvm_db_1
  port=5432 dbname=postgres " to address: Name or service not known



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  [32681]: could not translate host name "hhvm_db_1 port=5432 dbname=postgres " to a
  ddress: Name or service not known



  [PDOException]
  [32681]: could not translate host name "hhvm_db_1 port=5432 dbname=postgres " to a
  ddress: Name or service not known
```

The error message looks odd to me, because it states `dbname=postgres` while I have a different database specified in my parameters.yml. I tried to change it directly in the config.yml, but that does not change a thing. Database host and port are taken from my parameters.yml though.

I suppose doctrine is just using default parameters for dbname, as it cannot parse my parameters for some reason. What could be the problem here?

I don't think this is really the issue, but I am running symfony in a docker container with hhvm. `hhvm_db_1` in the above error message is the second container running Postgres. When I check the connection with vanilla PHP it works and I can connect to the database. Thus, the host is accessible from my web container.

Comment: Is it possible you're including another config file that might be overriding the dbname?

Comment: This is quite a fresh installation of symfony. There is only one `parameters.yml` and the config files for the different environments (test, dev, prod). None of them holds an additional database configuration. But that was why I asked for a way to debug the console script.

Comment: IIRC, including the command flag `-vvv` will increase the logging to the maximum level, which could help with debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This outputs the stack trace alongside, but it does not really produce something insightful.

Answer (score 1):

I found that my system is having problems with the dsn string containing spaces instead of semicolons.

Does not work:

```
pgsql:host=hhvm_db_1 port=5432 dbname=postgres
```

Works fine:

```
pgsql:host=hhvm_db_1;port=5432;dbname=postgres
```

My initial problem was also solved by that. The DBAL driver for PDOPgSQL is using postgres as the default database to check the connection.